# How to set different icons to every markers?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

How I can set different icons to every marker, Marker longitude and latitude are received from the server and I plot every device logitude and latitude on the map screen and remove the previous markers in every 5 seconds.

```
 try {
            //ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
            //TODO: remove previus markers
            if (marker != null) {
                mMap.clear();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Remove", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            for (LatLng object : latLngList)

            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("User Name").position(object).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.female4)));

            System.out.println(marker.getId()+"  Marker id.......");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // mMap.clear();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have marker image, and position (latitude and longitude) stored on the server. In retrieving the data from the server, you will get both. Here is a sample code:

```
if(googleMap != null){
        googleMap.clear(); // This will clear all of the previously added markers
        ArrayList<ServerItems> listOfItems = new ArrayList<>(); // Where ServerItems is your custom Model
        for(ServerItems item : listOfItems){
            LatLng position = item.getPosition(); // Assuming that Your Model ServerItems contains a method which returns LatLng
            String markerURL = item.getMarkerURL(); // Assuming that Your Model ServerItems contains a method which returns MarkerURL stored on Server
            ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(markerURL, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position));
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(loadedImage)));
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position));
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

Please note that, I am using [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) in order to load image in the form of Bitmap from the server.

Comment: please explain me what is MarkerUrl and Server items

Comment: As you said, Marker longitude and latitude are received from the server. You have to receive Marker Image URL as well from the server. So, I just assume a dummy model named as ServerItem which contains MarkerLatLng and MarkerURL